# PS4 to TV speakers, audio is lagging periodically

Tags: ps4, audio-hardware, hdmi

I am having a slight issue with my audio from my PS4. It randomly goes out of sync where the audio lags behind the video a decent bit. It is just a direct HDMI connection with nothing fancy.

I am curious if it has to do with my PS4 settings and it pushing too much data to the TV? I was using the PS4 with audio set to HDMI and L-PCM. Switching it to Optical (despite still using HDMI) and not checking any of the boxes seems to have helped so far...

I am curious if anyone knows the setting I should be using if the feed is just going directly to a TV with no speaker system?

Thank you.

Comment: Well, I'm going to assume pushing too much data to the TV isn't an issue. It's what they are built to do. Is the problem with one game/movie? Or across anything you play or watch?

Comment: It was across any HDMI device. All other signals and built in apps were okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a TV flaw. I exchanged the TV for a new one of the same model and have been trouble free since. The TV was a Sony W800C.